# Calling a function in a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code through COM

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, com

Apologies in advance for the following verbose question ; I am a COM noob.

**Scenario:** I need to [call a managed DLL built with C# from native Visual C++ code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736). In my native VC++ code, I do the following after registering "SomeDLL.dll" and generating the "SomeDLL.tlb" file with `RegAsm.exe`.

- Import the TLB file with `#import "SomeDLL.tlb"`
- Use the class `MyClass` defined in the DLL with `CComPtr<MyClass>`.

Everything's great! It compiles, and I can run the code etc. It hits the fan when I try to **run this application on a different machine** (i.e. not the one I compiled it on). I copy all the required DLLs, and I register the same DLL with `RegAsm.exe` but it doesn't work.

It specifically fails when it tries to initialize the COM library with `CoInitialize(0)` and returns the `S_FALSE` error which means

> The COM library is already initialized on this thread.

I can confidently state that I have not called this function anywhere else in my code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to help you find that code from here, you're a lot closer.  Maybe a DLL that gets injected.

Getting S_FALSE is *not* an error, getting RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE would be quite bad.  Be sure to use the FAILED macro:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    CallNineOneOne(hr);
    exit(hr);
}
```

Comment: What would recompiling accomplish?  Yes.

Comment: OK, instead of checking if `hr == S_OK`, I'm using the `FAILED` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you called OleInitialize or another function which calls ComInitialize behind the scenes.

Anyway, it does not matter to call CoInitialize several times per thread if you match each of them with a call to CoUninitialize